# mysql_upgrade affect replication mariadb from mysql

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I have one master (MySQL 5.7.29 ) and slave (MariaDB 10.4.12) I have a problem with events after inserting a dump to MariaDB from MySQL.

```
MariaDB [mysql]> show events;
ERROR 1545 (HY000): Failed to open mysql.event
```

select is working ok.

I follow this solution https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206335/150896 but I didn't execute the drop table for event.

1. Can I run mysql_upgrade on MariaDB? (The replication will have any problems?)
2. If I drop the table and recreate the have a different structure from MySQL and the engine is Aria. They will affect the replication also?

What is the safest way to fix this? mysql_upgrade or drop and recreate the table?

**Clean MariaDB**

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `db` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `body` longblob NOT NULL,
  `definer` char(141) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `execute_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `interval_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `interval_field` enum('YEAR','QUARTER','MONTH','DAY','HOUR','MINUTE','WEEK','SECOND','MICROSECOND','YEAR_MONTH','DAY_HOUR','DAY_MINUTE','DAY_SECOND','HOUR_MINUTE','HOUR_SECOND','MINUTE_SECOND','DAY_MICROSECOND','HOUR_MICROSECOND','MINUTE_MICROSECOND','SECOND_MICROSECOND') DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `last_executed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `starts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ends` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('ENABLED','DISABLED','SLAVESIDE_DISABLED') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ENABLED',
  `on_completion` enum('DROP','PRESERVE') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DROP',
  `sql_mode` set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH','EMPTY_STRING_IS_NULL','SIMULTANEOUS_ASSIGNMENT','TIME_ROUND_FRACTIONAL') NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `originator` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time_zone` char(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SYSTEM',
  `character_set_client` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `collation_connection` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `db_collation` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `body_utf8` longblob DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`db`,`name`)
) ENGINE=Aria DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PAGE_CHECKSUM=1 TRANSACTIONAL=1 COMMENT='Events'
```

**Broken MariaDB**

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `db` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `body` longblob NOT NULL,
  `definer` char(93) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `execute_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `interval_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `interval_field` enum('YEAR','QUARTER','MONTH','DAY','HOUR','MINUTE','WEEK','SECOND','MICROSECOND','YEAR_MONTH','DAY_HOUR','DAY_MINUTE','DAY_SECOND','HOUR_MINUTE','HOUR_SECOND','MINUTE_SECOND','DAY_MICROSECOND','HOUR_MICROSECOND','MINUTE_MICROSECOND','SECOND_MICROSECOND') DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `last_executed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `starts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ends` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('ENABLED','DISABLED','SLAVESIDE_DISABLED') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ENABLED',
  `on_completion` enum('DROP','PRESERVE') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DROP',
  `sql_mode` set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','NOT_USED','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH') NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `originator` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time_zone` char(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SYSTEM',
  `character_set_client` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `collation_connection` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `db_collation` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `body_utf8` longblob DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`db`,`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Events'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the differences between these two tables:

from broken to the mariadb-10.4 default that you listed as "Clean":

```
-  `definer` char(93) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
+  `definer` char(141) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

So definer is bigger because the allowed username is bigger.

SQL mode to ugly to display however the MariaDB has the extra modes:

- IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS
- EMPTY_STRING_IS_NULL
- SIMULTANEOUS_ASSIGNMENT
- TIME_ROUND_FRACTIONAL

Engine:

```
-) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Events'
+) ENGINE=Aria DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PAGE_CHECKSUM=1 TRANSACTIONAL=1 COMMENT='Events'
```

The engine doesn't matter to either mariadb or replication.

The upgrade to the new structure can be done with `mysql_upgrade` and is the recommended way.

I haven't looked how mysql event changes are replicated but structure wise, its compatible.

Comment: Thanks :) Is safe also for other tables for mysql database. Example(db, proc,.. ) replication it will effect?

I Can see proc and db they have one extra column in MariaDB (after mysql_upgrade)  but they have all default value.

Comment: `db` shouldn't matter. It is redundant. `proc` stores user functions and procedures. I'm fairly sure these are statement replicated. Test it out by creating a function on the master and seeing if the MariaDB replica processes it correctly. Everything is mean to be able to work with the exception of the [documented incompatibilities](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/incompatibilities-and-feature-differences-between-mariadb-103-and-mysql-57/#incompatibilities) (which I didn't see covering anything mentioned here). If you notice anything else, please write a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/).

Comment: thanks, i run mysql_upgrade all good :)